# iptables rules deleted after reboot on Kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, weave, kube-proxy

After manually adding some iptables rules and rebooting the machine, all of the rules are gone (no matter the type of rule ).

ex.

```
$ iptables -A FUGA-INPUT -p tcp --dport 23 -j DROP
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:telnet
```

After the reboot:

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

If I am not mistaken, `kube-proxy` running on every node is dynamically modifying the `iptables`. If that is correct how can I add rules that are permanent but still enable kubernetes/kube-proxy to do it's magic and not delete all the `INPUT`, `FORWARD` and `OUTPUT` rules that both Kubernetes and Weave plugin network dynamically generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `iptables` on **any** system is not a persistent action and would be forgotten on reboot, a k8s node is not an exception. I doubt that k8s will erase the IPTABLES rules when it starts, so you could try this:

- create your rules (do this starting with empty iptables, with `iptables -A` commands, as you need them)
- run `iptables-save >/etc/my-iptables-rules` (NOTE you could create a rules file manually, too).
- create a system service script that runs on boot (or use `/etc/rc.local`) and add `iptables-restore -n </etc/my-iptables-rules` to it. This would load your rules on reboot. Note if you use `rc.local`, your 'iptables-restore' command may well run after k8s starts, check that your `iptables -A` commands are not sensitive to being loaded after those of k8s; if needed replace the -A commands in the file with -I (to place your commands first in the tables).

(be aware that some OS installations might include a boot-time service that loads iptables as well; there are some firewall packages that install such a service - if you have one on your server, the best approach is to add your rules to that firewall's config, not write and load your own custom config).

Comment: That is a nice way to run service/startup scripts on boot time and that solves part of the problem, but because k8s dynamically creates rules, my static rule set changes order whenever I reboot (even though I set the rules with `-I`). I don't know when to start my script and make sure that some of the k8s rules are already applied. There is probably related with kube-proxy.

Comment: I have posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857978/implementing-iptables-rules-on-kubernetes-nodes) that points to the comment above , because the initial question was answered.