# Implementing iptables rules on Kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, kube-proxy

I would like to implement my own iptables rules before Kubernetes (kube-proxy) start doing it's magic and dynamically create rules based on services/pods running on the node. The kube-proxy is running in `--proxy-mode=iptables`.

Whenever I tried to load rules when booting up the node, for example in the `INPUT` chain, the Kubernetes rules (`KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES` and `KUBE-FIREWALL`) are inserted on top of the chain even though my rules were also with `-I` flag.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

If it is somehow related, I am using weave-net plugin for the pod network.

Answer (score 5):

The most common practice is to put all custom firewall rules on the gateway([ADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_delivery_controller)) or into cloud [security groups](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/). The rest of the cluster security is implemented by other features, like [Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) (It depends on the network [providers](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/reference/calicoctl/resources/networkpolicy)), [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) and others.

Check out the articles about [Securing a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/securing-a-cluster/) and [Kubernetes Security - Best Practice Guide](https://github.com/freach/kubernetes-security-best-practice).

These articles can also be helpful to secure your cluster:

- [Hardening your cluster's security](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster)
- [The Ultimate Guide to Kubernetes Security](https://neuvector.com/container-security/kubernetes-security-guide/)