# Only 1 pod handles all requests in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: go, kubernetes, load-balancing

Here is a manifest file for minikube Kubernetes, for a deployment and a service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: hello_hello
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4001
          protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
  - port: 4001
    nodePort: 30036
    protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
```

And a simple HTTP-server written in Golang

```
package main
import (
    http "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":4001",
        Handler: r,
    }

    server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

When I make several requests to *IP:30036/ping* and then open pod's logs, I can see that only 1 of 3 pods handles all requests. How to make other pods response on requests?

Comment: how do you make the requests?

Comment: @Thomas I open Postman, enter an IP address with the port 30036 and a path /ping. After that, I click the Send button several times and receive responses. Then I open logs of pods and see there that all requests go to 1 of 3 pods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are exposing a service using a NodePort, so there is no reverse proxy in place, but you directly connect to your Pod(s). This is a good choice to start with. (Later you might want to use an Ingress)

What you are seeing is that only one Pod handles your requests. You expect that each request is load balanced to a different pod. And your assumption is correct, but the load balancing does not happen on HTTP request layer, but on the TCP layer.

So when you have a persistent TCP connection and re-use it, you will not experience the load balancing that you expect. Since establishing a TCP connection is rather expensive latency wise usually an optimization is in place to avoid repeatedly opening new TCP connections: HTTP keep-alive.

Keep alive is by default enabled in most frameworks and clients, this is true for Go as well.
Try `s.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)` and see if that fixes your issue. (Recommended only for testing!)

You can also use multiple different clients, f.e. from the command line with curl or disable keep-alive in Postman.

Answer (score 5):

In Kubernetes cluster, requests that are sent to k8s services are routed by [kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/).

The default `kube-proxy` mode is `Iptalbles` since Kubernetes v1.2 and it allows faster packet resolution between Services and backend Pods. The load balancing between backend Pods is done directly via the `iptables rules`.

Maybe you're not generating enough load which one pod cannot handle, that's why you're routed to the same pod from `kube-proxy`.

You can also see the answer to this question for implementing custom `iptalbes-rule`:

- [Implementing iptables rules on Kubernetes nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857978/implementing-iptables-rules-on-kubernetes-nodes)

Answer (score 4):

thanks to @Thomas for the great insight ! I tried playing with the request header and it solved the load balancing issue where all requests where only hitting a single replica, whereas for demos or testing, it useful to be able to distribute requests to all replicas

from the doc:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: close

This request always hits the same pod

```sh
curl -H "Connection: keep-alive" http://your-service:port/path
```

However, using `close`, the request balanced to all pods

```sh
curl -H "Connection: close" http://your-service:port/path
```